# Why is my function and the print statements not working

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

> When squirrels get together for a party, they like to smoke cigars.
>
> A squirrel party is successful when there were between 40 and 60 (both inclusive) cigars, unless it is weekend when there is no upper limit on the number of cigars.
>
> Write a function cigar_party() that determines whether the party was successful or not.
>
> The function must receive as parameters an integer value for the number of cigars as well as an integer value to indicate a weekend. The function must then determine if it was a successful party or not and return a true (1) or a false (0) value (true for successful and false for unsuccessful) to the calling statement in the main program.
>
> Complete the Python program by asking the user to enter the number of cigars and indicate whether it is weekend or not. After that, the program must call the cigar_party() function with the values entered by the user.

This is what I have done:

```
cigars=int(input("Enter the number of cigars: "))
is_weekend=int(input("Is it weekend? 1=True, 0=False: "))

def cigar_party(cigars, is_weekend):
  if is_weekend and cigars >= 40:
      return True
      print("Yes! It was a successful cigar party!!!")
  elif cigars >= 40 and cigars <= 60:
      return True
      print("Yes! It was a successful cigar party!!!")
  else:
    return False
print("No, it was a disappointing cigar party...)
```

Comment: After `return`, no code in `cigar_party` will run anymore.

Comment: And you never actually called the function you defined.

Answer (score 1):

`return` statement should always be at the end, as it's the termination of the function. You also have to call a function, not just define it.

```
cigars=int(input("Enter the number of cigars: "))
is_weekend=int(input("Is it weekend? 1=True, 0=False: "))

def cigar_party(cigars, is_weekend):
  if is_weekend and cigars >= 40:
      print("Yes! It was a successful cigar party!!!")
      return True
  elif cigars >= 40 and cigars <= 60:
      print("Yes! It was a successful cigar party!!!")
      return True
  else:
    print("No, it was a disappointing cigar party...")
    return False

cigar_party(cigars, is_weekend)
```